# Gradle composite build dependency substitutions do not get applied

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, composite

I have an android application with a library dependency which I would like to be substituted by a local project as described in [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#defining_composite_builds)

build.gradle (Module: MyApp.app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.myname:lib_project_name:dev-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

settings.gradle (Project Settings)

```
include ':app'

includeBuild('../lib_project_name') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.github.myname:lib_project_name') using project(':')
    }
}
```

The lib project consists of two subprojects (an example app and the lib itself)

settings.gradle (Project lib_project_name)

```
include ':app'
include ':lib'
```

After syncing project with gradle files the lib got displayed in Android Studio as subproject but gradle throughs the warning

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
Could not resolve com.github.myname:lib_project_name:dev-SNAPSHOT.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I've read the documentation more closely and found that

> the composite build will substitute any dependency on [module] with a dependency on the `root project` of [library]

Changing `using project(':')` to `using project(':lib')` solved the problem.